# Finetune TFBertForMaskedLM model.fit() ValueError

Tags: tensorflow2.0, huggingface-transformers, huggingface-tokenizers

### The Problem

I have been trying to train TFBertForMaskedLM model with tensorflow. But when i use model.fit() always encounter some question.Hope someone can help and propose some solution.

### Reference Paper and sample output

The Paper title is "Conditional Bert for Contextual Augmentation". In short, just change type_token_ids to label_ids. if the label of sentence is 5, length is 10 and max_sequence_length = 16. It will process output as follows:

```
input_ids = [101, 523, 791, 3189, 677, 5221, 524, 1920, 686, 102, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
attention_mask = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
token_type_ids = [5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
labels = [-100, -100, 791, -100, 677, -100, -100, -100, -100, -100, -100, -100, -100, -100, -100, -100]
```

### Environment

- tensorflow == 2.2.0
- huggingface == 3.5.0
- datasets == 1.1.2
- dataset total label is 5. (1~5)
- GPU : GCP P100 * 1

### Dataset output (max_sequence_length=128, batch_size=1)

```py
{'attention_mask': <tf.Tensor: shape=(128,), dtype=int32, numpy=
 array([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
        1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
        1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], dtype=int32)>,
 'input_ids': <tf.Tensor: shape=(128,), dtype=int32, numpy=
 array([  101,   523,   791,  3189,   677,  5221,   524,  1920,   686,
         4518,  6240,   103,  2466,  2204,  2695,   100,   519,  5064,
         1918,   736,  2336,   520,   103,  2695,  1564,  4923,  8013,
          678,  6734,  8038,  8532,   131,   120,   120,  8373,   119,
          103,  9989,   103,  8450,   120,   103,   120, 12990,  8921,
         8165,   102,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
            0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
            0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
            0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
            0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
            0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
            0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
            0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
            0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
            0,     0], dtype=int32)>,
 'labels': <tf.Tensor: shape=(128,), dtype=int32, numpy=
 array([-100, -100, -100, -100, -100, -100, -100, -100, -100, -100, -100,
        4634, -100, -100, -100, -100, -100, -100, -100, -100, -100, -100,
        4158, -100, -100, -100, -100, -100, -100, -100, -100, -100, -100,
        -100, -100, -100, 8429, -100,  119, -100, -100,  100, -100, -100,
        -100, -100, -100, -100, -100, -100, -100, -100, -100, -100, -100,
        -100, -100, -100, -100, -100, -100, -100, -100, -100, -100, -100,
        -100, -100, -100, -100, -100, -100, -100, -100, -100, -100, -100,
        -100, -100, -100, -100, -100, -100, -100, -100, -100, -100, -100,
        -100, -100, -100, -100, -100, -100, -100, -100, -100, -100, -100,
        -100, -100, -100, -100, -100, -100, -100, -100, -100, -100, -100,
        -100, -100, -100, -100, -100, -100, -100, -100, -100, -100, -100,
        -100, -100, -100, -100, -100, -100, -100], dtype=int32)>,
 'token_type_ids': <tf.Tensor: shape=(128,), dtype=int32, numpy=
 array([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
        1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
        1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], dtype=int32)>}
```

### Model code

```py
from transformers import AdamWeightDecay, TFBertForMaskedLM, BertConfig

def create_model():
    configuration = BertConfig.from_pretrained('bert-base-chinese')
    model = TFBertForMaskedLM.from_pretrained('bert-base-chinese',
                                              config=configuration)
    model.bert.embeddings.token_type_embeddings = tf.keras.layers.Embedding(5, 768, 
                                                                            embeddings_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.TruncatedNormal(stddev=0.02))
    return model
model = create_model()

optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=3e-5)
loss = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True)
metrics = [tf.keras.metrics.Mean(), tf.keras.metrics.SparseCategoricalAccuracy('accuracy')]

model.compile(optimizer = optimizer,
              loss = loss,
              metrics = metrics)

model.fit(tf_sms_dataset, 
          epochs=1,
          verbose=1)
```

### Warning Message when use TFBertForMaskedLM

```
Some layers from the model checkpoint at bert-base-chinese were not used when initializing TFBertForMaskedLM: ['nsp___cls']
- This IS expected if you are initializing TFBertForMaskedLM from the checkpoint of a model trained on another task or with another architecture (e.g. initializing a BertForSequenceClassification model from a BertForPreTraining model).
- This IS NOT expected if you are initializing TFBertForMaskedLM from the checkpoint of a model that you expect to be exactly identical (initializing a BertForSequenceClassification model from a BertForSequenceClassification model).
All the layers of TFBertForMaskedLM were initialized from the model checkpoint at bert-base-chinese.
If your task is similar to the task the model of the checkpoint was trained on, you can already use TFBertForMaskedLM for predictions without further training.
```

### Error Message

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-42-99b78906fef7> in <module>()
      5 model.fit(tf_sms_dataset, 
      6           epochs=1,
----> 7           verbose=1)

10 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py in _method_wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs)
     64   def _method_wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
     65     if not self._in_multi_worker_mode():  # pylint: disable=protected-access
---> 66       return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
     67 
     68     # Running inside `run_distribute_coordinator` already.

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, validation_batch_size, validation_freq, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing)
    846                 batch_size=batch_size):
    847               callbacks.on_train_batch_begin(step)
--> 848               tmp_logs = train_function(iterator)
    849               # Catch OutOfRangeError for Datasets of unknown size.
    850               # This blocks until the batch has finished executing.

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwds)
    578         xla_context.Exit()
    579     else:
--> 580       result = self._call(*args, **kwds)
    581 
    582     if tracing_count == self._get_tracing_count():

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py in _call(self, *args, **kwds)
    625       # This is the first call of __call__, so we have to initialize.
    626       initializers = []
--> 627       self._initialize(args, kwds, add_initializers_to=initializers)
    628     finally:
    629       # At this point we know that the initialization is complete (or less

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py in _initialize(self, args, kwds, add_initializers_to)
    504     self._concrete_stateful_fn = (
    505         self._stateful_fn._get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected(  # pylint: disable=protected-access
--> 506             *args, **kwds))
    507 
    508     def invalid_creator_scope(*unused_args, **unused_kwds):

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py in _get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected(self, *args, **kwargs)
   2444       args, kwargs = None, None
   2445     with self._lock:
-> 2446       graph_function, _, _ = self._maybe_define_function(args, kwargs)
   2447     return graph_function
   2448 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py in _maybe_define_function(self, args, kwargs)
   2775 
   2776       self._function_cache.missed.add(call_context_key)
-> 2777       graph_function = self._create_graph_function(args, kwargs)
   2778       self._function_cache.primary[cache_key] = graph_function
   2779       return graph_function, args, kwargs

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py in _create_graph_function(self, args, kwargs, override_flat_arg_shapes)
   2665             arg_names=arg_names,
   2666             override_flat_arg_shapes=override_flat_arg_shapes,
-> 2667             capture_by_value=self._capture_by_value),
   2668         self._function_attributes,
   2669         # Tell the ConcreteFunction to clean up its graph once it goes out of

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py in func_graph_from_py_func(name, python_func, args, kwargs, signature, func_graph, autograph, autograph_options, add_control_dependencies, arg_names, op_return_value, collections, capture_by_value, override_flat_arg_shapes)
    979         _, original_func = tf_decorator.unwrap(python_func)
    980 
--> 981       func_outputs = python_func(*func_args, **func_kwargs)
    982 
    983       # invariant: `func_outputs` contains only Tensors, CompositeTensors,

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py in wrapped_fn(*args, **kwds)
    439         # __wrapped__ allows AutoGraph to swap in a converted function. We give
    440         # the function a weak reference to itself to avoid a reference cycle.
--> 441         return weak_wrapped_fn().__wrapped__(*args, **kwds)
    442     weak_wrapped_fn = weakref.ref(wrapped_fn)
    443 
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    966           except Exception as e:  # pylint:disable=broad-except
    967             if hasattr(e, "ag_error_metadata"):
--> 968               raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
    969             else:
    970               raise

ValueError: in user code:

    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:571 train_function  *
        outputs = self.distribute_strategy.run(
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:951 run  **
        return self._extended.call_for_each_replica(fn, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:2290 call_for_each_replica
        return self._call_for_each_replica(fn, args, kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:2649 _call_for_each_replica
        return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:541 train_step  **
        self.trainable_variables)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:1804 _minimize
        trainable_variables))
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/optimizer_v2/optimizer_v2.py:521 _aggregate_gradients
        filtered_grads_and_vars = _filter_grads(grads_and_vars)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/optimizer_v2/optimizer_v2.py:1219 _filter_grads
        ([v.name for _, v in grads_and_vars],))

    ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable: ['tf_bert_for_masked_lm_2/bert/embeddings/word_embeddings/weight:0', 'tf_bert_for_masked_lm_2/bert/embeddings/position_embeddings/embeddings:0', 'tf_bert_for_masked_lm_2/bert/embeddings/LayerNorm/gamma:0', 'tf_bert_for_masked_lm_2/bert/embeddings/LayerNorm/beta:0', 'tf_bert_for_masked_lm_2/bert/embeddings/embedding_1/embeddings:0', 'tf_bert_for_masked_lm_2/bert/encoder/layer_._0/attention/self/query/kernel:0', 'tf_bert_for_masked_lm_2/bert/encoder/layer_._0/attention/self/query/bias:0', 'tf_bert_for_masked_lm_2/bert/encoder/layer_._0/attention/self/key/kernel:0', 'tf_bert_for_masked_lm_2/bert/encoder/layer_._0/attention/self/key/bias:0', 'tf_bert_for_masked_lm_2/bert/encoder/layer_._0/attention/self/value/kernel:0', 'tf_bert_for_masked_lm_2/bert/encoder/layer_._0/attention/self/value/bias:0', 'tf_bert_for_masked_lm_2/bert/encoder/layer_._0/attention/output/dense/kernel:0', 'tf_bert_for_masked_lm_2/bert/encoder/layer_._0/attention/output/dense/bias:0', 'tf_bert_for_masked_lm_2/bert/encoder/layer_._0/attention/output/LayerNorm/gamma:0', 'tf_bert_for_masked_lm_2/bert/encoder/layer_._0/attention/output/LayerNorm/beta:0', 'tf_bert_for_masked_lm_2/bert/encoder/layer_._0/intermediate/dense/kernel:0', 'tf_bert_for_masked_lm_2/bert/encoder/layer_._0/intermediate/dense/bias:0', 'tf_bert_for_masked_lm_2/bert/encoder/layer_._0/output/dense/kernel:0', 'tf_bert_for_masked_lm_2/bert/encoder/layer_._0/output/dense/bias:0', 'tf_bert_f...
```

Have Someone can help. I will thanks a lot.

### Other Test

I used english sentence to test. example as follows:

```py
from transformers import TFBertForMaskedLM, BertConfig

def create_model():
    configuration = BertConfig.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased')
    model = TFBertForMaskedLM.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased',
                                              config=configuration)
    return model
    
model = create_model()
eng_tokenizer = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased')
token_info = eng_tokenizer(text="We are very happy to show you the  Transformers library.", padding='max_length', max_length=20)

optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=3e-5)
loss = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True)
metrics = [tf.keras.metrics.Mean(), tf.keras.metrics.SparseCategoricalAccuracy("acc")]

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(dict(token_info))
dataset = dataset.batch(1).prefetch(tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)

model.compile(optimizer = optimizer,
              loss = model.compute_loss,
              metrics = metrics)

model.fit(dataset)
```

token_info output dataset

```
{
  'input_ids': [101, 2057, 2024, 2200, 103, 2000, 2265, 2017, 103, 100, 19081, 3075, 1012, 102, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
  'attention_mask': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
  'token_type_ids': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
  'labels': [-100, -100, -100, -100, 3407, -100, -100, -100, 1996, -100, -100, -100, -100, -100, -100, -100, -100, -100, -100, -100]
}
```

Get same error.....

```
ValueError: in user code:

    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:571 train_function  *
        outputs = self.distribute_strategy.run(
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:951 run  **
        return self._extended.call_for_each_replica(fn, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:2290 call_for_each_replica
        return self._call_for_each_replica(fn, args, kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:2649 _call_for_each_replica
        return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:541 train_step  **
        self.trainable_variables)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:1804 _minimize
        trainable_variables))
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/optimizer_v2/optimizer_v2.py:521 _aggregate_gradients
        filtered_grads_and_vars = _filter_grads(grads_and_vars)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/optimizer_v2/optimizer_v2.py:1219 _filter_grads
        ([v.name for _, v in grads_and_vars],))

    ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable: ['tf_bert_for_masked_lm_2/bert/embeddings/word_embeddings/weight:0', 'tf_bert_for_masked_lm_2/bert/embeddings/position_embeddings/embeddings:0', 'tf_bert_for_masked_lm_2/bert/embeddings/token_type_embeddings/embeddings:0', 'tf_bert_for_masked_lm_2/bert/embeddings/LayerNorm/gamma:0', 'tf_bert_for_masked_lm_2/bert/embeddings/LayerNorm/beta:0',
```

I'm not sure if there is a problem with the integration of fit() into the model?